# Get custom itemsAdapter id using cursor android

Tags: android, database, cursor, cursor-position, custom-adapter

I'm trying to pass the item clicked to another activity i.e from A to B using a custom itemsAdapter with sqlite.

How can I achieve the following?

1)Get the item clicked position using cursor
2)Pass the item clicked to another activity

I'm trying to do similar to [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/) example but use my own custom adapter
I have dome the following so far.

Activity A:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this,F32Activity.class);
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) itemsAdapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("PROPERTY_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

startActivity(intent);
return;
 }
```

Activity B:

```
      propertyId = getIntent().getIntExtra("PROPERTY_ID", 0);
    System.out.println(employeeId);
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new Helper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db
            .rawQuery("SELECT * from my_table WHERE pro._id = ?",
                    new String[] { "" + propertyId });
```

Added the Adapter

```
private void getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void getDataAndPopulate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    image = new ArrayList<byte[]>();       
    bedrooms= new ArrayList<String>();
    address= new ArrayList<String>();
    propType= new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = getEvents(" gall,properties where  properties._id = gall._id  " );

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //String temp_id = cursor.getString(0);
        byte[] temp_image = cursor.getBlob(2);
        String temp_identifier = cursor.getString(1);
        String temp_price = cursor.getString(3);
        String temp_bedrooms = cursor.getString(4);
        String temp_address = cursor.getString(5);
        String temp_propType = cursor.getString(6);


        image.add(temp_image);
        //System.out.println(image);

        bedrooms.add(temp_bedrooms);
        address.add(temp_address);
        propType.add(temp_propType);


}
    String[] identifierArray = (String[]) bedrooms.toArray(new String[bedrooms
                                                                    .size()]);
   itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(PropertyResult.this,
   cursor, R.layout.activity_f9, identifierArray);
   setListAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}

private class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] items;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,int textViewResourceId,
            String[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public View getView(final int POSITION, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView desc;
        TextView cap;
        TextView ident;
        TextView pric;
        TextView bedroom;
        TextView addres;
        TextView propertytyp;
        View view = convertView;
        ImageView img;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_f9, null);

        }
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);        

        bedroom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bedrooms);
        addres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
        propertytyp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.propertytype);          


        bedroom.setText("£"+bedrooms.get(POSITION));
        addres.setText(address.get(POSITION));
        propertytyp.setText(propType.get(POSITION));

        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        image.get(POSITION), 0, image.get(POSITION).length));

        return view;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Please kindly give me a solution.

Comment: @Adil yes I'm recieving the following 04-07 10:43:13.348: E/AndroidRuntime(12696): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
04-07 10:43:13.348: E/AndroidRuntime(12696):  at com.studentAccommodationFinder.PropertyResult.onListItemClick(PropertyResult.java:87)
04-07 10:43:13.348: E/AndroidRuntime(12696):  at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onListItemClick()` you already have the row id from the cursor, is the 4th parameter, `id`(this only works for cursor adapters).

First of all also create and `ArrayList` that will hold `long` values(the row ids from the cursor):

```
ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
//...
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   String temp_id = cursor.getString(0);// if 0 is your column containing the id(check it)
   ids.add(temp_id);
   //...
}
```

Then in your adapter override the method `getItemId` and return the `long` values from the `ids` `ArrayList` according to the position supplied:

```
   public long getItemId(int position) {
        return ids.get(position);
    }
```

Then in your `onListItemClick()` simply use the `id` parameter:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,F32Activity.class);
   intent.putExtra("PROPERTY_ID", id);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in the receiving activity:

```
propertyId = getIntent().getLongExtra("PROPERTY_ID", 0);
```

Comment: Ok,if this only works for cursor adapter,how can i use it in my own custom item adapter?,your right on this one

Comment: @user1176963 You didn't say what's your custom adapter extending, `ArrayAdapter`, `BaseAdapter`, `SimpleCursorAdapter` etc?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,your solution will work however this is what i'm getting The method add(Long) in the type ArrayList<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (String)         that is when I try to do ids.add(temp_id);

Comment: @user1176963 Sorry, it should be `long temp_id = cursor.getLong(0);`

Answer (score 1):

Your on Item should like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {

    String strEventName, strEventDate;
    int Id;
    Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("PROPERTY_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    startActivity(intent);}
```

Comment: This does not give me an error however never gets clicked!,ONItemClicked not working.

Comment: check you have registered for listener and also check if your view has button than make it focusable false